# "Stream" is read-only error on run-time (after upgrading react-native to 0.56)

Tags: react-native

I just migrated from `react-native@0.53.3` to `react-native@0.56`. Also, as required, upgraded my node to 8+ (10.7.0) and babel to 7.0.0-beta.54. After completing the migration process, the following error showed up:

[image: rn-0 56-error]

Here are babel devDependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "7.0.0-beta.54",
  "@babel/preset-flow": "7.0.0-beta.54",
  "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
  "babel-jest": "22.1.0",
  "babel-preset-react-native": "5.0.2",
  "jest": "22.1.4",
  "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
},
"jest": {
  "preset": "react-native"
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?